# How do I create an empty folder in java?

Tags: java, directory

The problem I am having is that when I attempt to create the folder, it doesn't create. It might have something to do with the directory, but honestly I don't know. I tried using this:

```
File f = new File(javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory() + "/Levels/First Folder/Levels");
    try{
        if(f.mkdir()) { 
            System.out.println("Directory Created");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Directory is not created");
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it didn't work for me.

And this is the directory I put in the File, but I want the program to work on any computer: C:\Users\(My name)\Desktop\Levels\First Folder\Levels

Comment: When you say "it didn't work", does that mean it's printing an exception, does it mean your code doesn't compile, does it mean it's printing the fail message, or does it mean it prints the success message but it's not created?

Comment: It is printing the, Directory is not created, message

Comment: Did you check if the folder already exists?

Comment: Oh, only the desktop directory exists

Comment: Oh, yes, mkdirs worked. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, great. I've moved it to a proper answer.

Comment: It may be easier to use `System.getProperty("user.home")`, rather than `javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said only the Desktop directory exists, so you'll need to use [`mkdirs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) to construct the whole directory tree:

```
File f = new File(javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory() + "/Levels/First Folder/Levels");
try{
    if(f.mkdirs()) { //< plural
        System.out.println("Directory Created");
```

Keep in mind: you may want to check whether this directory exists before you try to create it, as it presumably isn't an error and is permissible to continue if your program has created it once before.

Answer (score 1):

Recommending `Files.createDirectories()` instead of `File.mkdirs()` because handling errors is more straightforward.

Thus:
`Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "/Levels/First Folder/Levels"));`

With `mkdirs()` it is difficult to determine if it failed, why it failed, or if it did not create the directory because it already existed.

Comment: I disagree that "it is difficult to determine if it failed". It can be difficult to determine *why* it failed, sure.

Comment: You can check pre-existence before attempting to create, but a race condition might occur. So there are conditions where it is difficult to determine *if* it failed. But OK I'll edit :)